COM processes in background - properly releasing COM objects
I built a WPF C# application which also updates some Excel Workbooks, but I'm not able to properly close all these processes despite using statements as per below:
(opening statements)
Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(..);`

(closing statements)
(wrapped in an Internal Static Class)
        public static void Exit(this Excel.Application XL)
        {
            foreach(Excel.Workbook workbook in XL.Workbooks)
            {
                workbook.Close(true);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
            }
            XL.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(XL);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

I know this last one is redundant but I tried them all to close the background processes I see in the Task Manager.
I saw also some similar threads, in particular this one but none of them worked for me.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you all

You have to make sure that nothing is referencing your XL object after passing it. It needs to be ready for garbage collection. Also, if you are running this from Visual Studio try release configuration instead of debug. In the past the debugger keeps excel open in the processes for whatever reason but in release everything works as expected.
